# Sliding text with div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I have a dropdown thingy. You click on the 'Click Me' text and it'll show. Here's a demo to it http://jsfiddle.net/QzLst/

Now here's the issue. The blue text on the right, *shows* even when I placed it in the `div` that slides up and down. I'm not really sure where to go from here. Here's my markup

```
<div class="search">
  <div class="text">
   Some text
 </div>
 </div>
 <div class="click">Click me</div>
```

And the CSS

```
.search{
    width: 100%;
    background: #000;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.1);
    z-index: 200;
    height:0;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
.toggle{
    height:100px;
}
.text{
    color: #009dff;
  float: right;
}
```

The demo will help you understand what I mean. All I want is the text to slide with the `div` named `search`. So when `search` closes, basically I guess `text` would also close

Comment: It doesn't slide with the container because you're manipulating height. You want to manipulate the actual y coordinates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `overflow: hidden` to `.search`.

Comment: One question. What if I wanted to slide a form up and down?

Answer (score 0):

This solves that problem:

[update to your fiddle] [http://jsfiddle.net/QzLst/1/][1](http://jsfiddle.net/QzLst/1/)

We can simply hide the `.text` class with this CSS:

```
.text {
    display: none;
}
```

Then we toggle the `.text` class:

```
$(".click").click(function(){
     $(".search").toggleClass("toggle");
     $(".text").toggle()
});
```

Comment: What if I wanted to slide a form? Some technique?

Comment: @user3100859 Yes, use the same technique so solve the problem in the second fiddle you provided a link to, here's the fixed/updated fiddle [http://jsfiddle.net/dxtU6/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/dxtU6/1/).

Comment: The link in the answer is 404